# BLE Gatt server - how to present a dropdown list as a service or characteristic?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

Everyone,

Could you please advise how can I present a dropdown list as a Gatt-server service or characteristic?

What I mean is the following:

- imagine a mobile is a Gatt client and it receives parameters from a BLE-enable device
- the raw data format is structured as a list of strings with associated numerical values corresponding to each string
- the issue is - how (using the specifications of the Gatt documentation) can one in a standardized way, applying the default Gatt UUIDs, represent this listed row data (described above) as a service or characteristic? I want to have it presented as a dropdown list of values in the client appilication (mobile app)?

Thanks in advance for your help and assistance!

Comment: If you have full control over both peripheral and app: Why can't you just send the data formatted in a special way (e.g. JSON) and construct your dropdown list on the app side? There is, to my knowledge, no gatt specification for a dropdown list

Comment: @M.Kotzjan, thanks for the contribution - this sounds as a very good idea - to received the data and then represent it as needed on the front-end (e.g. wrapped via the corresponding ReactNative components)